# Does tailwind merge work with prefixed tailwind classes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have to use tailwind classes with a prefix for conflict reasons, but tailwind merge doesnt seem to work with prefixed classes, like tw-flex-1 instead of flex-1

i tried this while debugging

```
console.log(twMerge("tw-bg-primary", "tw-bg-accent")); // logs "tw-bg-primary tw-bg-accent", but it should be "tw-bg-accent"
```

```
console.log(twMerge("bg-primary", "bg-accent")); // logs "bg-accent"
```

this works fine, but the classes dont work unless they are prefixed

Comment: I assume you are using tailwind-merge package. Have you configured the prefix described in https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/blob/v2.1.0/docs/configuration.md

Comment: @Leroy posted your reply as an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What [Leroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525872/leroy) said was the answer, this is what solved it:

```
import { extendTailwindMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

export const twMerge = extendTailwindMerge({
  prefix: "tw-",
});
```